# Como dar include em pagina js para fazer progressbar e voltar para o php

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, eu tenho um sistema para fazer upload de um arquivo e depois colocar os dados no banco de dados.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="formSendTorrent" id="formSendTorrent" name="formSendTorrent">

        <div class="defaultStyleSend fontDefault">
            <input type="file" multiple name="inputfileSendTorrent[]" id="inputfileSendTorrent"> 
        </div>
        <div id="progressBarCurrent">
            <div id="progbar"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submitSendTorrent" class="submitSendTorrent" value="Enviar">
    </form>

<?php
require DIR_FUNCS.'funcSQL.php';
require_once DIR_FUNCS.'Torrent.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitSendTorrent']))
{   
    echo 'começo';

    $i = 0;

    $uploaddir = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave.'/';

    include DIR_FUNCS.'progressBar.js';

    foreach ($_FILES["inputfileSendTorrent"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
    {
        $arqName = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['name'][$i];
        $arqTemp = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if(!@move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $uploaddir.$arqName))
        {
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo $error['message'];
        }

        $i++;
    }

    echo 'final';
} 
?>
```

progressBar.js

```
$(function() 
{
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm(
    {
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
        {
            document.getElementById("progressBarCurrent").style.display = 'block';
            var total_perc = total | 0;
            var current_perc = position | 0;
            document.getElementById("progbar").innerHTML = Math.floor((current_perc / (total_perc / 100)) * 100) / 100 + '%';
            document.getElementById("progbar").style.width = current_perc / (total_perc / 100) + '%';
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

O include não funciona, porem se eu colocar a `progressBar.js` na mesma pagina ele faz o progresso certinho, porem ele não executa o php.

Eu quero executar o PHP, e apenas no momento que for fazer o upload que ele faça progresso na barra, o código acima é resumido para entender melhor, porem no código original eu faço testes antes de fazer upload do arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu ai estás a misturar alhos com bugalhos... ao fazeres o include do ficheiro progressBar.js dentro do php, basicamente estas a dizer ao interpretador que o que ele tem de fazer é ler o ficheiro progressBar.js como se tivesse codigo php, e nao é isto que tu queres

O que terás de fazer, é no teu html utilizar a tag script com o src a apontar para o caminho do teu ficheiro progreebar.js

**Não olhei o resto do teu código, mas presumo que o teu script esteja bem feito**

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho que fazer alguma testes em PHP, e depois fazer o upload do arquivo(junto com a barra de progresso em JS), e depois voltar para o PHP para inserir os dados retirados desse upload no banco de dados.

Comment: Todos os códigos funcionam(a barra de progresso, inserir no BD, os teste), oque eu estou com dificuldade mesmo é fazer a barra de progresso subir apenas no momento que eu quero, que no caso é depois dos testes(se o arquivo tem nome, quando to pesa, etc) e depois dela subir, tem que voltar para fazer a inserção no BD.

Comment: Desculpa, não estou a entender o que tu queres, a mim parece-me que o te tu queres e uma pagina normal que faça algum request ao servidor(php->mysql) e que durante esse tempo, o utilizador veja uma barra de progress, isto sem contar os testes

Comment: Aconselho-te a reformular a tua pergunta, adicionando exemplos...

Comment: Vou tentar explicar de uma forma simples, quando o usuário enviar um arquivo, o sistema vai receber ele, fazer alguns testes em PHP, logo após com o mesmo form fazer upload do arquivo(ao mesmo tempo que faz a barra de progresso), e depois disso usa o arquivo que fez upload para inserir alguns dados no BD. 
O meu problema é que, se eu colocar o código que está dentro da progressBar.js no mesmo arquivo que eu chamo o form em PHP, ele ignora o form em PHP e usa apenas o form em JS.